# Save dataframes with a foor loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, time

I am trying to save streamflow data from USGS using the data Retrieval package of R. It was working until now, but I am not what I changed that it is not working anymore, this is my code:

```
siteNumber <- c("094985005","09498501","09489500","09489499","09498502","09511300","09498400","09498500","09489700")

i <- 1
n <- length(siteNumber)

for (i in n) {
  
  Daily_Streamflow <- readNWISdv(siteNumber[i],parameterCd="00060", statCd="00003", "","")
  name <- paste("DSF", siteNumber[i], sep = "_")
  assign(name, value = Daily_Streamflow)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Now is saving only as data frame the data for the last station. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `for (i in 1:n)` as your for loop

Comment: It's a bad idea to write items to the global environment like this. It's much tidier, more convenient and safer to store them in a list. You could get the entire list with `DSF <- lapply(siteNumber, readNWISdv, parameterCd="00060", statCd="00003")`, without having to use loops or assign functions. You can get each dataframe as easily (e.g. `DSF$'094985005'`) and if you need to perform manipulations or searches on all your frames you can do it very easily with `lapply`

Answer (score 0):

Read ?`for`. A `for()` loop iterates over a sequence. You do not need to explicitly increment the index (that is how e.g. `while()` loops)

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  
  Daily_Streamflow <- readNWISdv(siteNumber[i],parameterCd="00060", statCd="00003", "","")
  name <- paste("DSF", siteNumber[i], sep = "_")
  assign(name, value = Daily_Streamflow)
}
```